# Valid Stored Procedure not returning any results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bt_BizForSale_GetByID]
(
@ID int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT      dbo.bt_BizForSale.UserID, 
            dbo.bt_BizForSale.VendorType,
            dbo.bt_BizForSale.BusinessName, 
            dbo.bt_BizForSale.isEmailSubscriber,
            dbo.bt_BizForSale.isIntermediarySubscriber, 
            dbo.bt_Regions.Region AS Country, 
            bt_Regions_1.Region AS Province, 
            bt_Regions_2.Region AS City,
            dbo.bt_BizForSale.[AdType]

FROM         dbo.bt_BizForSale INNER JOIN
                      dbo.bt_Regions ON dbo.bt_BizForSale.[61] = dbo.bt_Regions.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.bt_Regions AS bt_Regions_1 ON dbo.bt_BizForSale.[62] = bt_Regions_1.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.bt_Regions AS bt_Regions_2 ON dbo.bt_BizForSale.[63] = bt_Regions_2.ID

WHERE     (dbo.bt_BizForSale.ID = @ID)
```

And when I execute it with a **VALID ID** from the table, it's not returning any results.  What could I possibly be missing?

PS: on "most" valid ID's I pass to the stored procedure, I get the results I'm looking for.

Example:  10010 will return results, but 10104 will not.  Both are valid records in the database.

Comment: Did you try to execute your just the query with that value? Does it return any row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a Region ID in the [61], [62], [63] columns which is not in dbo.bt_Regions (or is NULL, which will never satisfy any equality condition)

INNER JOIN requires that the (equality) condition be satisfied - so a row must be found

If any one of your INNER JOINs does not have a satisfied condition, you will get no rows.

You will need to either correct your foreign keys to be valid or change to a LEFT JOIN with appropriate handling of NULLs when the right hand side has no rows satisfying the join criteria

Comment: Yeah, he should change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: that's exactly it. So how can I "fix it" to allow for NULL 61,62,63?

Comment: Just change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, as I wrote above.